# IIS Adding URL instead of IP

Tags: asp.net, iis, web

I have a local only ASP.NET MVC app hosted in IIS, and I was wondering how I could use a URL instead of an IP? At the moment I access it using `http://127.0.0.1`, but I'd like something like `http://foo` instead

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is an analog of `http://localhost` anyway (it should already be in your hosts file). You can add a new entry into the hosts file for `127.0.0.1` by following this guide: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS, you need to add a binding to the website, here you can specify the hostname i.e. foo.xyz.com

However, you will need to make sure that the DNS resolves that hostname to your IP address

Answer (score 0):

You could add this line to your  host file:

`127.0.0.1 foo`

You can find the host file here:
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc